# Quadratic Diophantine equation in $\mathbb Z[T]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the following quadratic diophantine equation in $\mathbb Z[T]$:
$$((T+1)X+TY-1-Z)((T+1)X+TY-1+Z)=24XY$$
One has the following trivial solutions:
$(X,Y,Z)=(0,Y,\pm(1-TY))$, $(X,0,\pm(1-(T+1)X))$. Can one describe all the solutions of this equation (at least an algorithm to obtain all of them)?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: First, it might be easier to first ask for solutions in $\mathbb C[T]$, then if those can be characterized, figure out which ones are in $\mathbb Z[T]$. Second, some motivation for your problem would be nice. (It's easy to make up lots of equations. For example, why 24?) Third, you previously asked a related, albeit easier, question (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/211874/); it's helpful if you indicate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number $T$ is set by the problem statement. Then in the equation.

$$((T+1)x+Ty-1-z)((T+1)x+Ty-1+z)=24xy$$

The solutions can be written as.

$$x=\pm{s}(p((6-T-T^2)s\pm{T})+1)$$

$$y=p((T+1)s\mp1)$$

$$z=(pT\mp1)(s(T+1)\mp1)-p(s(T+1)\mp2)(T\mp{s}(T^2+T-6))$$

$$***$$

Symmetric solution to the previous one.

$$x=p(Ts\mp1)$$

$$y=\pm{s}(p((6-T-T^2)s\pm(T+1))+1)$$

$$z=p(s(T^2+T-6)(\pm{Ts}-2)\pm(T+1))\mp{Ts}+1$$

$p , s - $ any polynomials.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on how you get these?

Comment: @IgorRivin don't understand the question.  The equation is easy to solve it.

Comment: If it is easy to solve, it should be easy to explain how you got the solution...

Comment: Did anyone test this answer? by plugging in numbers?

Comment: @Individ: Maple does not agree with your solution. I took $p=4$ and $s=3$. With your first solution one has $$((T+1)X+TY-1-Z)((T+1)X+TY-1+Z)-24XY=10368T^3+13824T^2-58464T-41904$$

Comment: @joaopa  If Maple does not agree, then this problem Maple, not mine.  Carefully substitute and check. You should have in the first formula. $$x=3(73-8T-12T^2)$$ $$y=4(3T+2)$$ $$z=(T-2)(36T^2+120T+37)$$  Or this.  $$x=3(12T^2+16T-73)$$  $$y=4(3T+4)$$  $$z=2(3T+4)(12T^2+16T-73)$$

Comment: I checked your two solutions solution Both are correct. But you did not give any proof that there does not exist other solutions. Mathematics is not a matter of trust but proofs

Comment: Downvoting because the question asks for _all solutions_, and individ does not give any justification for his or her claim that this method produces all the solutions.